# Crop the certain portion of image based on view placed on camera

Tags: android, image, crop

Hi need to cut the certain portion from image view or while capturing image through camera. Like below

[image]

Please help me.

I tried and i got to crop the rectangle shape not for custom shape. Here is the code which i did for rectangle shape

```
   val bh = bitmap.height
        val bw = bitmap.width
        val width = vF_atv_camera_preview!!.width;
        val height = vF_atv_camera_preview!!.height;
        val location = IntArray(2)
        vL_atv_box!!.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        val l = location[0] * bw / width
        val t = location[1] * bh / height
        val w = vL_atv_box!!.getWidth() * bw / width;
        val h = vL_atv_box!!.getHeight() * bh / height;
        val resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, l, t, w, h);
```

Comment: Please post the code. so we get know what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can project the Camera2 Preview on a TextureView (which is more flexible and "manageable" than a SurfaceView) and then place a normal "ImageView" below it which has those two holes in its Drawable.

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see there is a small TextureView in the center with two ImageViews on its top and bottom showing a gradient (white-to-transparent Shape Drawable), but the Camera in portrait mode is filling the whole white space.

Comment: Thanks! How can i crop the certain portion from that. Could you please elaborate little more. It will be really helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the update! but it seems like i will not get the cropped image. I want the bitmap of cropped hole image.

Comment: @user get hole's Bitmap and mantain Preview a stable framerate could be not possibile because the device cannot be fast enough to crop the Bitmap to assure a smooth Preview. If you are interested in a single "screenshot" you can take the Preview image and then crop it using a Bitmap Mask.